# diagnostic software for wifi adapter

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, diagnostic

I'm having trouble with my wifi connection. Is there any software out there that can help me determine if the problem is in the drivers or in the hardware?

Regretfully, I'm working on Vista

**Edit:**

The problem I'm having is that the Vista reports that the wireless radio is connected, shows an IP and all, the router also shows that the computer is connected, but there's no connectivity. I can't logon to the router, and I can't even ping it.  When I ping it I get the response:

```
General Failure
```

- I have tried connecting with and without various wireless security protocols.
- I have tried disabling the wireless adapter and re-enabling it from the Device Manager
- I have tried updating the driver

None of this has helped.

When I connect via Ethernet (with a cable, that is), everything works fine.

**Edit:**

I'm not using any firewall on the computer, that I'm aware of.

The IP address for the WIFI adapter is similar to the one for the LAN adapter. They differ by one.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Perhaps we can solve it for you directly.

Comment: Are you running firewall software on the computer? What is the IP address you are assigned? Is it similar to the IP address you are assigned when connected via ethernet?

Comment: To rule out the WAP: are other devices successfully connecting to your wifi network, and/or is your computer able to connect to other wifi networks successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see wireless networks, let alone connect to them, the odds of there being anything wrong with your hardware are infinitesimal.  I'd look to software on this one.

Comment: That's my thought as well, except that once I connect, there's no outgoing traffic. That's why I want to check the hardware, to rule that out.

Comment: If you can negotiate the initial connection (which you can if the router shows clearly whether or not you are disconnected) every time that you try, then the transmitter and antenna are fine.  There's really nothing else that I'm aware of that you can do.

Has this specific connection worked fine previously?  Is the firmware on the router current?  You might possibly try flashing it.